# Update command error

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I want to update a row by code in my form. Maybe some columns are null. So while command is 
executing, an error will rise and say Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where':

```
SqlCommand Update = new SqlCommand("Update Table_065_Turn SET Column02=" + Row["Column48"] + "  , Column15= " + Row["Column15"].ToString()  +
" where ColumnId=" + StatusTable.Rows[0]["ColumnId"], Con);
 Update.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I know this error will be displayed because Row["Column15"] is null.
How can I check if the column in datarow is null; of course without any extra variable or commands before Update command. 
I mean check columns exactly in update command.

Comment: Is ROW, a data row? You should use a string builder instead of doing it directly

Comment: You are more likely to get future answers if you accept the answer that helped you on questions you've already asked.  It's not that hard to do.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using SqlParameters, also `SqlCommand` implements `IDisposable` so you should wrap it up in a `using` statement e.g.

```
using (SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("Update Table_065_Turn SET Column02=@Col2, Column15=@Col15 where ColumnId=@ColId", con))
{
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col2", Row["Column48"]);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col15", Row["Column15"]);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColId", StatusTable.Rows[0]["ColumnId"]);
    update.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Also you might be better actually validating the fields *before* you execute the query unless null is a valid column value.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have to "replace" .net `null` with database keyword NULL, e.g.
`string sql = "Column15 = " + (row[15] == null ? "NULL" : row[15].ToString())` in your case, but the much better way is to use Parameters as written by James, also keep in mind someone could provide hamful strings to your query:

`row[15] = ";DROP DATABASE; --"` would be enough in your case to cause all your data to be lost ;) (see "SQL injection" on your favorite search engine

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
var value = "" + Row["columnname"] ;
```

so ,you do not need to check the object is null

it is safe..

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
string filterString;
if (StatusTable.Rows[0]["ColumnId"]!=System.DBNull.Value)
  filterString= @" WHERE ColumnID= StatusTable.Rows[0]["ColumnId"]";//I assume the value returned is a string
else
  filterString="";
```

And then you can just append the filterString variable to your SQLCommand string.